# Does the order of hdf5 close matter?

Tags: hdf5

I am implementing a HDF5 layer in an interpreted language with automatic reclamation facilities (garbage collect).

When a proxy to a HDF5 entity (H5File, H5Group, H5Dataset, H5Dataspace, H5Datatype, etc...)  will be no longer referenced, it will be automatically reclaimed. With ephemeron like facility, I can arrange to be noticed and invoke the corresponding close function automagically (H5Fclose, H5Gclose, H5Dclose, etc...) in order to release the target resource.

By default, I have no control on the order of reclamation. However, if ever order of close counts, then I can arrange to keep a strong pointer on a parent proxy (for example the H5 File) from within any other entity. If order does not count, then I will avoid this useless complication.

So my questions:

1. Can I invoke `H5Fclose(fid);` before `H5Gclose(gid);` where previously `gid=H5Gcreate(fid,'/foo',H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);`?
2. Can I continue to operate on the group once I closed the containing file? For example, is it legal to call `H5Fclose(fid);` before `gid2=H5Gcreate(gid,'bar',H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);` in above example? If not, are there other entities concerned, or is it just file?

Answer (score 0):

Doh, case of blindness, the documentation tells that close is delayed until all objects have been closed, so 1. order does not count and 2. is legal.

https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/RM_H5F.html#File-Close

However, it may not work in every circumstances, so it's not recommended.

> H5Fclose terminates access to an HDF5 file by flushing all data to storage and terminating access to the file through file_id.
>
> If this is the last file identifier open for the file and no other access identifier is open (e.g., a dataset identifier, group identifier, or shared datatype identifier), the file will be fully closed and access will end.
>
> Delayed close:
>      Note the following deviation from the above-described behavior. If H5Fclose is called for a file but one or more objects within the file remain open, those objects will remain accessible until they are individually closed. Thus, if the dataset data_sample is open when H5Fclose is called for the file containing it, data_sample will remain open and accessible (including writable) until it is explicitely closed. The file will be automatically closed once all objects in the file have been closed.
>
> Be warned, however, that there are circumstances where it is not possible to delay closing a file. For example, an MPI-IO file close is a collective call; all of the processes that opened the file must close it collectively. The file cannot be closed at some time in the future by each process in an independent fashion. Another example is that an application using an AFS token-based file access privilage may destroy its AFS token after H5Fclose has returned successfully. This would make any future access to the file, or any object within it, illegal.
>
> In such situations, applications must close all open objects in a file before calling H5Fclose. It is generally recommended to do so in all cases.